# Mongodb $slice doesn't slice the data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, slice

When trying to slice collection users, and logging it to the console the fields that are supposed to be sliced aren't for some reason.

```
var filteredUsers =
 users.find({},
    {
        "followers": { "$slice": -1 },
        "subscribers": { "$slice": -1 },
        "hour": { "$slice": -1 }
    }
 ).toArray();

filteredUsers.forEach(user => {
    console.log(user);
});
```

i'm using mongodb version above 3.2 so this shouldn't be an issue here.

output of the log:

```
{
 _id: 'fakeId',
 subscribers: [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null, 0 ],
 followers: [ 1, null, 1, null, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 ],
 hour:
 [ 313347,
  316733,
  316735,
  316968,
  316969,
  317349,
  317350,
  318746,
  318747,
  324667
 ]
}
```

Comment: I have mongo db version v3.6.5. And it works fine with me.

Comment: [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.2/reference/operator/projection/slice/) projection has been introduced in version 2.2 so it is not an issue here @Jack... And @Arin your code works see here https://mongoplayground.net/p/_1sBpuQNOuO... Might be the issue is with `.toArray()` here

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Seems like toArray() could indeed be one of the issues all though after removing it i'm still getting not sliced data. Could it be that it's and issue with the fact that .find() returns a cursor?

Comment: yes... use callback or promise or async await here

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you upgrade MongoDB version to **v3.6.5**.

Your above query works like butter, here is the output:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "fakeId", 
    "subscribers" : [
        0.0
    ], 
    "followers" : [
        1.0
    ], 
    "hour" : [
        324667.0
    ]
}
```

Let me know if this upgrade works.